# Установка чекнутого RadioButton без вызовa onCheckefChange

Tags: android

В моем адаптере происходит биндинг данных

```
void bind(int position){
        TriggerModel trigger = triggers.get(position);
        int state = trigger.getState();
        int id = rg.getChildAt(state).getId();
        rg.check(id);
}
```

Но этот способ вызывает `onCheckedChange`. Как просто выбрать `RadioButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно делают так:

- убрать onCheck listener
- проставить\убрать check
- вернуть onCheck listener

Comment: Спасибо, догадался уже сам, просто не отписался :)